# BTEQ on Windows

Tags: teradata

New to teradata and would appreciate your answer to this very simple questions:

a 20 page BTEQ script (run on UNIX) has been given to me, that inserts into 50 teradata tables, varying between 10,000 to 60,000 rows, 10 columns, from .csv and .txt files.

Any advice as to to going from BTEQ Unix to a batch file that I can run from Windows command prompt? I've read about writing a batch file, .bat, but in terms of the structure of the script, am I wasting my time trying to alter current code, or will I have to rewrite it? I guess my question is, how different is UNIX BTEW TO Windows Command Prompt Unix.

Thank you very much. I'm new to programming, and it's all very interesting right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTEQ is available on various Unixes/Mainframe OSes and Windows.

Unless there are some `.OS`commands with Unix-specific commands (like `rm`) in it you can probably run this script as-is using the Windows version of BTEQ.

Comment: As long as the "BTEQ script" is plain BTEQ source.  If it's really a shell script, it likely needs to be re-written (or install cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)! This will give you a unix/linux shell running on windows.